# Importing from a parent directory in Python does not work

Tags: python, import, directory

Even with an `__init__.py` in the parent directory.

```
parentDir\
    __init__.py
    targetDir\
        __init__.py
        something.py
    thisDir\
        main.py
```

In main.py:

```
import .targetDir.something
```

This does not work. I tried:

```
from . import targetDir
from targetDir import something
```

This doesn't work, either. Are there any Pythonic solutions for doing something as simple as importing a module from a directory in the parent directory?

Comment: You need `__init__.py` in `thisDir` as well.  You should also read [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11536764/attempted-relative-import-in-non-package-even-with-init-py) and [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/python-relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you'd need `__init__.py` in `thisDir` and then you need to go up a level in the package hierarchy:

```
from ..  import targetDir
```

or:

```
from ..targetDir import something
```

Answer (score 0):

May be this is not a cleanest solution, but you can do something like this:

```
import sys
import os

topdir = os.path.normpath(os.path.join(os.path.abspath(sys.argv[0]),
                                       os.pardir, os.pardir))
if os.path.exists(os.path.join(topdir, "targetDir", "__init__.py")):
    sys.path.insert(0, topdir)

from targetDir import something
```

#### Example:

```
mkdir -p parentDir/targetDir
mkdir -p parentDir/thisDir
touch parentDir/__init__.py
touch parentDir/targetDir/__init__.py
echo "print 'Im here'" > parentDir/targetDir/something.py
```

then place the code in `parentDir/thisDir/main.py` and it should print `Im here`